# Abrir ventanas desde un botón en Java Swing

Tags: java, java-swing, menú

Estoy desarollando un proyecto para una materia de la Uni. He creado un Menú con Java Swing. Quiero que al presionar un botón del formulario me abrar la carpteda documentos de mi Pc. ¿Alguien ha hecho algo así por el estilo?       ¿Alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Muchas gracias de antemano chicos!

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAVA TIENE UNA CLASE QUE SE ENCARGA DE LA BUSQUEDA DE ARCHIVOS INCLUSO PUEDES ESPECIFICARLE QUE TIPO DE ARCHIVOS AQUI UN EJEMPLO:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
        "JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif");
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
       System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +
            chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
    }
```

Comment: Gracias bro, ya pude solucionar mi problema.